# Toggle active class for the child or its relevant siblings onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on a navigation link, I can successfully toggle the state.navigation between true and false which then sets the class on the navigation component.

However it only changes the link I have clicked on without swapping the other ones back ! I need a solution that also removes all the active links form the NavItems I have previously clicked.

```
 class NavItem extends Component{ 

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          navigation: false,
      };
  }

     toggleClass() {

      this.setState({ navigation: !this.state.navigation });

  };

    render(){
        return(
                <li><Link 
                    to={ this.props.href } 
                    className={ this.state.navigation ? 'active' : null } 
                    onClick={ () => this.toggleClass() }>{ this.props.text }</Link>
                </li>
            )
    }

}

class Navigation extends Component{ 

    render() {
        return(
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <NavItem href='galleries' text='Galleries' />
                    <NavItem href='archive' text='Archive' />
                    <NavItem href='news' text='News' />
                    <NavItem href='about' text='About' />
                    <NavItem href='contact' text='Contact' />
                    <NavItem href='map' text='Map' />
                </ul>
              </nav>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: It is `NavLink` in case `react-router` 4 is used, here is [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) about how to use `NavLink`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to lift your state up and implement the same logic like

```
class NavItem extends Component{ 

     toggleClass = ()  => { 
       this.props.toggleClass(this.props.text);
     };

    render(){
        return(
                <li><Link 
                    to={ this.props.href } 
                    className={ this.props.active ? 'active' : null } 
                    onClick={this.toggleClass}>{ this.props.text }</Link>
                </li>
            )
    }

}

class Navigation extends Component{ 


    constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       this.state = {
          navigation: '',
       };
    }
    toggleClass = (items) => {
       this.setState(prevState => ({ navigation: prevState.navigation === items? '': items }));
    };
    render() {

        return(
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <NavItem href='galleries' text='Galleries' toggleClass={this.toggleClass} active={this.state.navigation === 'Galleries'}/>
                    <NavItem href='archive' toggleClass={this.toggleClass} text='Archive' active={this.state.navigation === 'Archive'}/>
                    <NavItem href='news' toggleClass={this.toggleClass} text='News' active={this.state.navigation === 'News'}/>
                    <NavItem href='about' toggleClass={this.toggleClass} text='About' active={this.state.navigation === 'About'}/>
                    <NavItem href='contact' toggleClass={this.toggleClass} text='Contact' active={this.state.navigation === 'Contact'}/>
                    <NavItem href='map' toggleClass={this.toggleClass} text='Map' active={this.state.navigation === 'Map'} />
                </ul>
              </nav>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow that works. I was hoping React could handle this with much less code but I guess not. What is the 'prevState' stuff you did please @shubham ?

Comment: @margaretkru, That could be the way to go, this answer possibly covers senarios where you need to do it yourself

Comment: @32423hjh32423, the prevState thing is a syntax for setState when you need to make use of prevState to update the currentState, it was required here because you need to check whether the current active item is the same as the one being clicked on

Comment: @Shubham, yes, you are right. I realized that there was nothing mentioned about using `react-router` in the question, in that case it is necessary to implement the functionality yourself.